# Docker not getting installed in ubuntu14.04

Tags: docker

I am trying to install Docker in ubuntu14.04 ,which is running as a guest Operating system using vmware playstation 12 in windows 8 system.

I am following the steps provided in the docker website . When ever i am typing the command

```
sudo wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

in the terminal, nothing is getting downloaded.

My ubuntu14.04 instance is completely updated.

Comment: which message is showing when you writting this command?

Comment: Nothing, just a prompt to enter the password that's all. After entering the password nothing happens.

Comment: have you updated your apt-get list by writting this command => sudo apt-get update

Comment: Yup , i have checked whether wget is installed or not and also updated the system using sudo apt-get update.

Comment: I installed it inubuntu14.04 using  virtualbox before and it worked all fine , but in vmware playstation 12 it is showing problems.

Comment: did you try to "ping" get.docker.com from inside the VM? Also, what does `wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/` give you? Does it show the install script?

Comment: @thajeztah , Ping wasn't happening and so changed the network settings of the vmware playstation to enable it , Now it got installed .Thnx for your advice,  I should have checked it before.

Comment: Great! so everything works now?

Comment: @thajeztah , yeah everything is working now